# Google Maps API: ZERO RESULTS or INVALID REQUEST while drawing routes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to draw a route based on the co-ordinates that i receive from the database. But somehow i am not able to draw. I either get `ZERO RESULTS` or `INVALID REQUEST`.. The route i am trying to draw is a `TRANSIT` ROUTE. Where as i found some similar issues([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836096/my-directions-api-request-is-invalid-but-why)) being addressed in the site but the solution given was to add `departure time` or `arrival time` in the parameters. And it was an accepted answer. The same which i tried is not working currently. I have posted the code that i have tried.
Below are the co-ordinates:

```
19.1860640243063 72.9759523272514
19.1902699 73.023094
19.2178474133021 73.086293040406
19.2354157727173 73.1302742969937
```

Please help.

```
 load : function(response) 
        {
            for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
            {
                if(response[i].linkData!='undefined')
                {
                 link=response[i].linkData;
                 var lastPos=(response.length-1);
                 linkDes=response[lastPos].linkData;    
                 var linkDes=link.split(" ");       
                 var linkValue=link.split(" ");                                          
                 var latDes= parseFloat(linkDes[0]);                
                 var longDes= parseFloat(linkDes[1]);           
                 var lat = parseFloat(linkValue[0]);  //convert string to float                 
                 var lon = parseFloat(linkValue[1]);  //convert string to float             
                 if(count==0)
                 {   
                   var source=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon); 
                   count++;
                 }  
                 if(i!=0 )  
                 {
                     geoLatLong=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon); 
                      count++;
                 }
                 if(i!=response.length-1)
                 {
                     geoLatLong=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);   
                 }
                 if(latDes!="" && longDes!="")
                  {         
                     var destination=new google.maps.LatLng(latDes, longDes); 
                  }
                  if(count>1 && count<=response.length-1) 
                  {
                   geoLatLongArray.push(geoLatLong);   
                  }

                }
            }
            for(var i=0;i<geoLatLongArray.length;i++)
            {
              waypts.push({location:geoLatLongArray[i],stopover:true}); 
            }
            var request = {
                    origin: source,
                    destination: destination,
                    waypoints: waypts,
                   optimizeWaypoints: true,

                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT,
                    transitOptions: 
                    {
                     departureTime: new Date()   
                    }
                };
                directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                  } else {
                    alert("directions response "+status);
                  }
                });
        }
```

Comment: Can you link the original question you followed?

Comment: @ Geocodezip: I am able to draw routes using waypoints from the above code for TRANSIT using way points....!...I am facing issue only for some routes...And the link provided above does not have any answer that would solve my question's purpose..so it should not be marked as duplicate...!

Answer (score 0):

According to [v3 API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TravelModes)

```
google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
```

is the correct syntax.

Comment: how does your waypts array look?  Might be easier to throw your code into a jsfiddle?

Comment: I have edited my question added the link which i had referred(accepted answer). And its not that the waypoints dont work for me. It works for one or two routes, but not for all..If i use a directionservice object for every route that i draw...I mean to say no way points.The transit service works fine..:-(

Comment: Is there a significant difference in the number of waypoints for routes that work, against routes that don't?  Sorry for all the questions, your syntax looks fine now, so it must be an issue with either the storage of the waypoints, or the way they're being iterated through

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I fixed it after making origin to an address field (instead of coordinates). this issue persists only when both origin and destination are coordinates.

You can perhaps convert your coordinates into address using [Reverse Geocode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) and then pass the converted addresses to origin / destination.